# What is trigonometry?

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry, education

I am going to learn trigonometry next year. I am an advanced student and I like to get a head start on things.  So,

> How do you describe and introduce Trigonometry to the advanced secondary school student who has had Algebra and Geometry?

A supplemental question is

> What are the best texts or websites to introduce the subject to a curious or independent learner?

Comment: www.google.com is a good one

Comment: www.wikipedia.org is also a good one.

Comment: Wikipedia has a very complete approach about trigonometry. If you are looking for more advanced stuff I suggest having a look at wolfram.

Comment: Some more details will be appreciated (your grade, your age, what do you know, ...). That way we can recommend more suitable materials.

Comment: Why 4 downvotes in 3 min? He's a new user, just give him a chance to add more details.

Comment: You might want to work on your style a little.

Comment: It is the study of trigs.

Comment: Don't be mean to me.

Comment: Try [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Trigonometry-Demystified-2-Stan-Gibilisco/dp/0071780246). I think you can download it for free .

Comment: Ok. I will take a look

Comment: For a different perspective, consider the following statement: "Trigonometry is entirely encompassed in SOHCAHTOA and Euler's identity."  Read up on this a bit and you may find some interesting stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Trigonometry is the study of triangles.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

It has vast applications in the real world and in theoretical maths.  Wikipedia actually is one of the better starting points for learning about it.  The introduction from Wolfram is more straightforward and less helpful for a newcomer:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trigonometry.html

If you really want to start studying on your own, the Kahn Academy is a great place to listen to lectures:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry

Personally I found this book fascinating, it provides wonderful context for the basic subject, and you may continue to amaze (and annoy) your teachers by quoting from it.  The reading could be difficult (or boring) for you, I would look for one in the library before buying it.  But when you have to write a history paper, perhaps you can use this as a reference to write about mathematics if you find this subject more interesting!

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Mathematics-Heavens-Earth-Trigonometry/dp/0691129738](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691129738)

Comment: Ok. Thank you that book looks very useful my parents just bought it for me and it will be delivered in 2 days. OK

Comment: After you have had a look at it, come back and tell us if you think it is interesting or boring, helpful or unhelpful for you.

Comment: Ok I will. It will probably be interesting anyway

Answer (score 2):

> *What is trigonometry ?*

The thing with the angles and the three-letter functions... Unless you meant it philosophically, as in *What is art ?*, and whatever...

Answer (score 1):

Literally, the study of triangles.  Since a triangle may either be specified by its edge lengths or by its angles (up to scaling), in practice this means that trigonometry studies the relationship between angles and side lengths.  Traditionally, the focus is on right triangles, which represent the majority of the challenge (any triangle can be cut into two right triangles).

Since there are triangles everywhere, trigonometry has many implications, for example in the motion of planets, springs, pendula, and waves.